# How to use Terraform output as input for Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

Using terraform and Azure ARM template, want to use Terraform output as input for Azure ARM Template. Need help to decide what will the best way to perform this action.

1. How to store the terraform output in KeyVault/Storage/Tables
2. Use the output for ARM template input

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How to store the terraform output in KeyVault/Storage/Tables

The output of the Terraform is defined by yourself. So you can decide what is the output. And to store them in the KeyVault/Storage/Tables, just create the resources of them. For example, you want to store the VM resource Id as a secret, then you can do it like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  ...
}

...

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  value        = azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

> Use the output for ARM template input

For the ARM template in Terraform, you can take a look at the [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html). And you can there is a property `parameters` in it. All the parameters in the ARM template, you can add the inputs in the parameters to set them. For example:

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "example" {
  name                = "acctesttemplate-01"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  template_body = <<DEPLOY
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_ZRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account type"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
DEPLOY


  # these key-value pairs are passed into the ARM Template's `parameters` block
  parameters = {
    "storageAccountType" = "Standard_GRS"
  }

  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
}
```

You can see the parameter `storageAccountType` in both parameters property of the resource `azurerm_template_deployment` and the ARM template. Also, the example that you want to set the VM resource Id for the parameter in ARM template with the output of the Terraform, you can do it like this to pass the Terraform output into the ARM template:

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "example" {
      name                = "acctesttemplate-01"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

      template_body = <<DEPLOY
    {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "vm_resource_id": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      ...
    }
    DEPLOY


      # these key-value pairs are passed into the ARM Template's `parameters` block
      parameters = {
        "vm_resource_id" = azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id
      }

      deployment_mode = "Incremental"
    }
```

Comment: yes, but I want to store the ``terraform output`` to secret, then use the secret in ARM template deployment. Is it possible. As I have multiple output values.

Comment: @user47 As I know, it seems it's impossible to achieve that at one time. You just can use the output files existing before you execute the Terraform this time. And I think the output files just store the messages which you can get them inside the Terraform code. Why do you want to do it via the output file?

Comment: I need this terraform output files to store somewhere as key-value and use it to another deployment with ARM template

Comment: it can be any azure resources or using azure-devops

Comment: @user47 If you mean the output from `terraform output`. You need to understand what is the output. Take a look at [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html). Then why do you quote them inside the Terraform where you want to execute?

Comment: I have made some alternate way, after terraform apply will run powershell script to store the mentioned outputs in Azure keyvaults. Then use those as parameters in ARM. Not sure if there is any better option

Comment: @user47 I'm not clear if you understand what is the output. When you use the command `terraform output`, it means all the outputs are stored in the state file and define in the terraform code. So I'm now a little confused about what you really expect?

Comment: I know it's bit difficult to explain in comment. I am using ```terraform output``` from ```terraform apply```, then storing the values in Azure KeyVault. Then using it for future deployments, i,e using ARM

Comment: @user47 Can you give an example that the output you want to store in the Key vault from the `terraform output`? Do you know only you define the output inside the Terraform code, then you can output it from the `terraform output` command?

Comment: yes, I am defining the outputs I want. e.g. I want resource group name from the output. So I am storing .PSObject.Properties.Name as secret name and the .PSObject.Properties.Vale.value as secret value. Then refering the secret in ARM template deployment.

Comment: @user47 OK, then why not you just create the secret directly in the Terraform to store the group name for the next ARM deployment?

Comment: can't do that as we have different teams, one team only works on terraform. Other team use ARM, and they need output from our scripts

Comment: @user47 I mean you store the things in the key vault directly as need. They can use it via getting the secret from the key vault for the ARM deployment. There is no conflict.

Comment: @user47 Any more question? Does it solve your problem?